# Message Integrity Check with HTTP headers since Content-MD5 was deprecated?

Tags: rest, http-headers, md5, integrity

Making a REST web server mainly based on large files uploads / downloads, I want to be able to check the file integrity. I believed that the proper way to do it was using Content-MD5 HTTP header [0] as proved useful by aws experience [1].

However, much to my dismay, I recently learned that it was (to be ?) deprecated [2].

The deprecation discussion did not give any workaround hint, so I am asking you :

Should I still decide to use a Content-MD5 HTTP header ?

Should I use an ETag with the same meaning (base64 encoding of the md5sum) ?

Should I use an ?md5sum=XXX parameter ?

Is there a better solution altogether ?

Thanks for your insights.

Best Regards,
B.

[0] https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/

[1] http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=22709

[2] http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/178

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Content-MD5: it has been deprecated because it leads to inconsistencies.

Use Digest with sha-256 or sha-512. We are updating [RFC3230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3230.html) to the latest HTTP specification ([RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html)) and added a lot of useful examples https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-02

```
Digest: sha-256=4REjxQ4yrqUVicfSKYNO/cF9zNj5ANbzgDZt3/h3Qxo=
```

There Want-Digest allows requesting a specific Digest header.

Eg. The client requests a digest, supporting sha-256 and sha-512. The server replies with sha-256

Request:

```
GET /items/123 HTTP/1.1
Want-Digest: sha-256, sha-512
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Digest: sha-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=

{"hello": "world"}
```

---

> ***2023** Note: The *Digest* field-name has been *obsoleted* per the (currently) latest draft ([-13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13)), there in [*7.1. HTTP Field Name Registration*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#section-7.1) has a nice overivew:*
>
> IANA is asked to update the "Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Field Name Registry" registry ([[HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110)]) according to the table below:
>
> | Field Name | Status | Reference |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Content-Digest | permanent | [Section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#content-digest) of this document |
> | Repr-Digest | permanent | [Section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#representation-digest) of this document |
> | Want-Content-Digest | permanent | [Section 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#want-fields) of this document |
> | Want-Repr-Digest | permanent | [Section 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#want-fields) of this document |
> | Digest | obsoleted | [[RFC3230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3230.html)], [Section 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#obsolete-3230) of this document |
> | Want-Digest | obsoleted | [[RFC3230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3230.html)], [Section 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-13#obsolete-3230) of this document |

Comment: Are there any web servers that do support Want-Digest as built-in option for static content? Or you always need to implement this header behaviour yourself every time? I am looking for a ready tool.

Comment: Usually servers configured to return `Digest` always do it, but there are some plugins around, eg. https://github.com/search?q=want-digest&ref=opensearch

`Want-Digest` is more useful when using Digest as a building block to implement some more logic in your API.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom header, called say `X-YourService-Integrity`. That makes it explicit that it's a system specific to your service, and allows you to use integrity check mechanisms other than MD5 in the future (for example, SHA1). It also avoids you having to "overload" existing mechanisms that are similar but not quite what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, a custom http header can be dropped during transfer and I don't see an advantage over ETag that could be used for any integrity check as the validator implementation is left open by the standard http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3

Comment: Why would a header be dropped during transfer?

Comment: Thank you for following up on this matter. I'm currently searching the text (I'm sure I've been reading that implementations SHOULD only keep non standard headers, but I cannot find an authoritative reference. For the record, the "X-" naming convention is discouraged http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-saintandre-xdash-03 .

Comment: I'm not sure how many other desirable options you have left, then. ETag is meant to be server-assigned, and this is a client-assigned value. The URI is not the place for it either as the integrity hash is related to the representation, not the server resource. And while X- headers are discouraged, there are ways outlined in that link you posted to add custom headers. This is meta data, and meta data belongs in a header. How you structure that header is up to you and your application's needs.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3230.txt

4.3.2 Digest

The Digest message header field provides a message digest of the
   instance described by the message.

```
  Digest = "Digest" ":" #(instance-digest)
```

The instance described by a message might be fully contained in the
   message-body, partially-contained in the message-body, or not at all
   contained in the message-body.  The instance is specified by the
   Request-URI and any cache-validator contained in the message.

A Digest header field MAY contain multiple instance-digest values.
   This could be useful for responses expected to reside in caches
   shared by users with different browsers, for example.

A recipient MAY ignore any or all of the instance-digests in a Digest
   header field.

A sender MAY send an instance-digest using a digest-algorithm without
   knowing whether the recipient supports the digest-algorithm, or even
   knowing that the recipient will ignore it.

Examples:

```
  Digest: md5=HUXZLQLMuI/KZ5KDcJPcOA==
  Digest: SHA=thvDyvhfIqlvFe+A9MYgxAfm1q5=,unixsum=30637
```

Comment: Are there any web servers that do support Want-Digest as built-in option for static content? Or you always need to implement this header behaviour yourself every time? I am looking for a ready tool.